# Types of Intermediate Representations

Tags: compiler-construction, language-agnostic, compiler-optimization

As I've researched on the Internet about compilers, I've run across a few different types of [Intermediate Representations](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/ir/), including plain AST's, Single-Static Assignment, Continuation-Passing Style, and others. However, there doesn't seem to be one place listing all of them.

If you implemented a compiler (or another piece of software with an IR), what type of IR did you use and why? What did you like about it, and what annoyed you?

Comment: I'm okay with deleting this, if it seems like a bad question.

Comment: Its not a bad question.  There are people at SO that don't like these kinds of questions.  (I'm not one of them.  I'd write you an answer, but these people are going to close the question on you anyway, so I'll just provide you with a link "offsite": http://www.quora.com/How-are-IR-instructions-usually-stored-inside-a-compiler/answer/Ira-Baxter)

Comment: @IraBaxter, thanks! I've got the answer. I was also thinking that I would ask this question again on programmers.stackexchange. In retrospect, that seems like a better place to put it.

Comment: If it seems like a good idea, can someone please migrate this to programmers?

Answer (score 3):

Way back when I was building compilers, the "Dragon Book" was my goto reference for compiler related stuff http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools should help you find a recent edition.)

If the new versions are as good as the old ones were you'll have more information than you can easily digest.

To me, one of the key issues regarding representation has always been how to generate meaningful error messages and relate them to source lines.